# URL Rewrite - Router script vs .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

What is the best method of rewriting URLs, in terms of best performance? The two main methods I am aware of are:

1. `.htaccess` rewrite, meaning all requests and rewrites are handled by the `.htaccess` script
2. Router script - this uses `.htaccess` to redirect every request to `index.php`. Then some code in `index.php` rewrites the request

Comment: It depends on how complex your routing is.

Comment: Using the rewrite engine in apache will most likely be faster since alternative 2 will require invoking php for each page request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on whether or not you want to use a [MVC Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or not. In both cases, you're using the rewrite engine, but if you don't want to use MVC/a routing script, or if you have static HTML content, you may as well just go with option 1. If you have static HTML content, just serving the content as-is is going to be faster than executing php.

Comment: What does routing have to do with MVC?

Comment: @blockhead A lot of MVC frameworks use a router, and unless you want to use one of those frameworks, I don't think it's worth it to have everything route through index.php. At least not having routing just for the sake of it. It's going to be slower than serving static files.

Comment: You can use a router without an MVC framework, and you can use an MVC framework without a router. They are completely orthogonal.